# Poetry: How to find root libraries when using python?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I just started to use poetry for my python projects and have an essential question. Let's say I have the following directories in my root folder.

- src/data
- src/models

When running a file in src/models (or a python shell in this folder), I'd like to import my own modules as follows:

- from src.data import xyz

However, python does not know the path to my root directory. Is there a poetry-specific way of adding the path or how do you handle it in this setup?

Comment: As far as I know, if there is a `src` directory it is handled differently in Poetry. I believe it is handled as if you wanted to use the so-called "src-layout". In this layout, your top-level import packages would be `data` and `models`. But you seem to want `src` to be the top-level import package. So you might need to add to the `[tool.poetry]` section of your `pyproject.toml` the following: `packages = [{include = "src"}]`.

Comment: @sinoroc Thank you for your quick response. I just added the suggested line to my toml-file. Unfortunately, without any success. My module is still not found.

Comment: Which commands are you running? From which directory?

Comment: When I start a python shell in src/models and run from src.data import test, where test is my python file, I get the error: No module named 'src'

Comment: Are you sure the `src` package is installed and importable?

Comment: hmm, what do you mean exactly with installed? I simply added the line packages = [{include = "src"}] to my pyproject.toml file. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Did you run `poetry install`? -- Also, maybe simply something went wrong, and you could try deleting the virtual environment and recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `__init__.py` files in your folders? They are required even if you leave them blank

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).